# Exporting: Checking if offline

Tags: highcharts, export, legend, offline

For my standard chart I don't use a legend, but when exporting it, I would like to include the legend. So I configured the chart like this:

```
myChartInstance.update({"exporting": {"enabled": true, "menuItemDefinitions": {"downloadPNG": {"onclick": function() {myChartInstance.update({"legend": {"enabled": true}}); this.exportChart(); myChartInstance.update({"legend": {"enabled": false}});}}}}});
```

So onclick

1. I switch the legend on
2. then call this.exportChart();
3. Switch legend off again

Unfortunately this doesn't consider the offline-exporting option.
So, when my network is offline there is an error message.

How can I solve this?

Comment: What's the error message ?

Comment: You do not have to update your chart - you can set additional options in exporting.chartOptions - see the example https://jsfiddle.net/tfjb13cf/